# svg css animation infinite

Tags: css, svg-animate

I am trying to make a similar example like https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works but I would like it to rotate infinite.

```
#path1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 170;
  -webkit-animation: animate1 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  animation: animate1 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes animate1 {
 to {
       stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
 to {
       stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
}
```

I made an example http://jsfiddle.net/46cmu71t/. I put the code to do this infinite but it slow down and then start again. Is there any way to make it rotate without losing speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very easy to do, add the `linear` method to the transition line:

```
#path1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 170;
  -webkit-animation: animate1 5s infinite linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
  animation: animate1 5s infinite linear;
}
```

[More about CSS transition timing](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/)
[More about CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_transitions)

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46cmu71t/1/)

Comment: is there any way to rotate clockwise? or i should change the path?

Comment: hi! i am trying to make it rotate faster when hover on the inside rect. but mozilla dont do it properly. is there any fix? chrome do it fine! check it please http://jsfiddle.net/46cmu71t/4/

Comment: The best thing i can think of is remove the transition for FF:http://jsfiddle.net/46cmu71t/5/ it jumps a tiny bit, but its barely noticeable

Answer (score 1):

Might want to read up a bit more on [CSS Animations](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/). The property you’re looking for is called a timing function. By default an animation is set to `ease-out`, and you should be using `linear` instead. E.g.

```
#path1 {
    stroke-dasharray: 170;
    -webkit-animation: animate1 5s infinite linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    animation: animate1 5s infinite linear;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mfgmxhqm/